# One-Class Support Vector Machines

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, analytics, data-mining, svm

So I want to make sure I have this right. First, I'm an undergrad computer engineering major with much more hardware/EE experience than software. This summer I have found myself using a clustering algorithm that uses one-class SVM's. Is an SVM just a mathematical model used to classify/separate input data? Do SVM's work well on data sets with one attribute/variable? I'm guessing no to the latter, possibly because classification with a single attribute is practically stereotyping. My guess is SVM's perform better on datasets that have multiple attributes/variables to contribute to classification. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This isn't really programming related. The answer to your first question is [yes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine); the answer to your second question you're much more likely to find on http://stats.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SVM tries to build **hyperplane** separating 2 classes (AFAIK, in one-class SVM there's one class for "normal" and one class for "abnormal" instances). With only one attribute you have one-dimensional space, i.e. **line**. Thus, hyperplane here is a **dot** on the line. If instances of 2 classes (dots on this line) may be separated by this hyperplane dot (i.e. they are linearly separable), then yes, SVM may be used. Otherwise not.

Note, that With *several* attributes SVM still may be used to classify even linearly unseparable instances. On the next image there are 2 classes in two-dimensional space (2 attributes - X and Y), one marked with blue dots, and the other with green.

[image]

You cannot draw line that can separate them. Though, so-called [**kernel trick**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_trick) may be used to produce much more attributes by combining existing. With more attributes you can get higher-dimensional space, where all instances *can* be separated ([video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3liCbRZPrZA&feature=player_embedded)). Unfortunately, one attribute cannot be combined with itself, so for one-dimensional space kernel trick is not applicable.

So, the answer to your question is: *SVM may be used on sets with only one attribute if and only if instances of 2 classes are linearly separable by themselves*.

Comment: This answer is a bit misleading: nobody would use the SVM without the kernel trick. Without the kernel trick the SVM is just a slightly-improved Perceptron, which was already well understood in the '60s.

Comment: @Bean: both perceptrons and SVM (and many others!) are just names for concepts, actual methods/implementations have lots of details. Yes, under some conditions they become equivalent, under other conditions -very different. But the important are their main ideas and their impact on machine learning field. For example, perceptron  is in essence logistic regresson model, but invention of ANNs lead to such things as Kohonen maps. And now we can see how idea of kernels, introduced in SVMs, goes to neural networks.